# What is the intuition behind a Euclidean function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Many algebra textbooks give the definition of a Euclidean domain as an integral domain $R$ equipped with a Euclidean function/map (let's call it $\nu$). What I don't understand is the significance of the property frequently stated as:

$\forall a,b\in R \colon\ \nu(a) \leq \nu(ab)$.

I understand the other property as it allows the Euclidean algorithm to be performed, but I don't understand the purpose of this particular property.

Thanks.

Comment: If you consider the mentions of (EF2) which that property is called [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Properties) you see that it is related to being able to identify the invertible elements and the number of irreducible factors.